# Can't pull Office field from search template driven employee directory in 365

Tags: office-365, search-results, people-search

I'm setting up an employee directory as seen on Marc's blog here http://sympmarc.com/2014/12/21/create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-employee-directory-on-office365-part-1-introduction/.

The issue is that the office field won't come in. The `ManagedPropertyMapping` tag includes "**OfficeNumber**" but for some reason the `ctx.CurrentItem` won't pull back that particular field. I can do a search for "**OfficeNumber**: **Vinings**" for instance and it works correctly. I've spent hours trying to sort this out and I'm getting no where. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is my ManagedPropertyMapping tag:

> 'AboutMe':'AboutMe','AccountName':'AccountName','Office':'OfficeNumber','Department':'Department','HitHighlightedProperties':'HitHighlightedProperties','Interests':'Interests','JobTitle':'JobTitle','LastModifiedTime':'LastModifiedTime','Memberships':'Memberships','PastProjects':'PastProjects','Path':'Path','PictureURL':'PictureURL','PreferredName':'PreferredName','Responsibilities':'Responsibilities','Schools':'Schools','ServiceApplicationID':'ServiceApplicationID','SipAddress':'SipAddress','Skills':'Skills','UserProfile_GUID':'UserProfile_GUID','WorkEmail':'WorkEmail','WorkId':'WorkId','WorkPhone':'WorkPhone','YomiDisplayName':'YomiDisplayName'

Comment: Have you tried using 'OfficeNumber':'OfficeNumber' instead of your current mapping?

Comment: Thank you Mathew, and yes I have tried that as well. ctx.CurrentItem still won't pull it.

Comment: Return to the Result Type Rules page and see if you see a message about updating the Properties. It may be that additional processing is needed. Beyond that you can troubleshoot the JavaScript to find clues.

Comment: Thanks again Mathew. For some reason I never get that prompt under "Search Result Types" or "Search Query Rules".

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved after multiple support calls with Microsoft. They told me they had other customer support tickets describing the same issue. After a few weeks of back and forth, the office field began to work just as expected. They claimed they didn't do anything on their end but I have my doubts since I had not touched the site. I wish I could post a more detailed and helpful solution, but in this case it just started working.